# Potential Resource Leak in Return

Tags: java, eclipse, return, resource-leak

I'm trying to return the value of PreparedStatement from a method and Because of that I cannot enclose statements in the method with try catch. Is there any way I can get rid of the resource leak of PreparedStatement with return statement?

```
public PreparedStatement getStatement(){
final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connection
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM log");
return preparedStatement;
}
```

Comment: It is just a warning, if you are sure (after double checking) you don't leak any resources, you can ignore it.

Comment: Please show the code of your method, algorithm with how you typically invoke it. If the method is a factory, there is no problem with suppressing the warning.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can get rid of that resource leak, create a expiry hashmap with a call back onexpiry(https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jodah/expiringmap/ExpiringMap.java like this many open source libraries are available).

So you can put your prepared statement while getting it for first time and for subsequent times you can retrieve it from map.

You can set a default expiry period for the map and in callback close all the prepared statements.